# How can I recognize keyboard presses in ios?

Tags: ios, keyboard, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I have looked all over for an answer to this but essentially what I am trying to do is when a person pressed the colon key on their iphones keyboard I want to be notified and perform a certain action. I hope this makes sense. If you do offer an answer keep in mind I am a relatively new IOS developer :)

Thanks!

edit: Incase my above statement didn't quite make sense this is what will happen ideally:

1. user taps on textfield
2. user presses the number 1 key
3. notification is sent that user pressed the number 1 key
4. instead of the number 1 printed, the text will be replaced with the number 2.

this is a simple example.

Comment: Is this for a `UITextField` or a `UITextView`?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: So it would be the textfield delegate rather then the keyboard? I need the notification before the enter/return key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, use this callback and change in there:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{

    //check here if the new character is the one you are looking for
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
         //create a new string with the character you want to use instead
         NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"A"];

         //set it as the text for your text field
         [textField setText:newText];
         return NO;
    }

     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a delegate method for a UITextField where if the user tries to enter an uppercase character it will appear as a lowercase character instead:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
        replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString* lc = [string lowercaseString];
    if ([string isEqualToString:lc])
        return YES;
    textField.text =
        [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                withString:lc];
    return NO;
}
```

You should be able to do something similar for your particular use case.

Comment: That is pretty much what I am looking for as far as changing out the letters so thank you! Although it appears as though what will happen is once the user enters the full sentence it would then change around what is typed. How would I receive a notification from the keyboard so that for example: when user types a, it changes to A, user types p, changes to P etc.